# Prism pop-up new window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

How can I open/close a new window in WPF without violating rules of the MVVM pattern?
 I just want to mimic the login module of ms office outlook.

I've already read [this article](http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/04/20/implement-a-confirmation-dialog-in-wpf-with-mvvm-and-prism/), but there are an error in passing a parameter `confirmation`

I'm currently using prism 5.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Do you use Prism 7?**  
**if Yes, then stop reading now and go to [this Prism 7 answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61555337)** 
**if No, then continue reading**

---

***Update** 

What lead me to put another answer was the inability to apply the accepted answer on my project **which using the Prism 6**, 
 but after putting the original answer (see it below) and discussing it in comments, I discovered that the core problem was:  The **Prism 6** changed the namespaces of some classes, all the classes which used in the accepted answer is still exists in **Prism 6**, but in another dlls and namespaces

**So if you are using Prism 6**, you can apply the accepted answer with those modifications*

first replace those namesapces

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:pi="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity"
xmlns:pit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity.InteractionRequest;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity"
```

with the following namespaces

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
```

second update the **XAML** as the following

```
<Button Content="Options" Command="{Binding OpenConnectionOptionsCommand}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding OptionSettingConfirmationRequest, Mode=OneWay}" >
            <prism:PopupWindowAction>
                <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                    <views:CustomPopupView />
                </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction>
        </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

**NOTE 1** 
Make sure that the view you are using (in the example above `<views:CustomPopupWindow>`) is NOT a window, or you will receive an exception.

**NOTE 2** 
These modifications are required **ONLY** in case you are using Prism 6. because (As I said in the Original Answer below) the dlls which used by the accepted answer is *deprecated* in Prism 6.

**NOTE 3** 
Make sure you are referencing the `Prism.Wpf` dll, which could be [downloaded from Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Wpf/).

---

**Original Answer** 
The ***accepted answer*** is directed to the *Prism 5*, it uses [this library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Interactivity) which is *deprecated* in the *Prism 6*.

Actually [the article which you reference](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/04/20/implement-a-confirmation-dialog-in-wpf-with-mvvm-and-prism/) in your question was very helpful (at least for me), and it does not crash.

I will try to summary that article.

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        _showWindowCommand = new DelegateCommand(ShowWindow);
        _interactionRequest = new InteractionRequest<Confirmation>();
    }

    private readonly DelegateCommand _showWindowCommand;
    private InteractionRequest<Confirmation> _interactionRequest;

    public ICommand ShowWindowCommand
    {
        get { return _showWindowCommand; }
    }

    public IInteractionRequest InteractionRequest
    {
        get { return _interactionRequest; }
    }

    private void ShowWindow()
    {
        _interactionRequest.Raise(
            new Confirmation(),
            OnWindowClosed);
    }

    private void OnWindowClosed(Confirmation confirmation)
    {
        if (confirmation.Confirmed)
        {
            //perform the confirmed action...
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Button Command="{Binding ShowWindowCommand}" Content="Show Window" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Raised" SourceObject="{Binding InteractionRequest}">
            <i:EventTrigger.Actions>
                <local:ShowWindowAction></local:ShowWindowAction>
            </i:EventTrigger.Actions>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

and you will need to use those namespaces

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:The namespace which contains the ShowWindowAction">
```

**ActionTrigger**

```
using System;
using Prism.Interactivity.InteractionRequest;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using System.Windows;

public class ShowWindowAction : TriggerAction<FrameworkElement>
{
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        InteractionRequestedEventArgs args = parameter as InteractionRequestedEventArgs;
        if (args != null)
        {
            Confirmation confirmation = args.Context as Confirmation;
            if (confirmation != null)
            {
                // Replace ParametersWindow with your own window.
                ParametersWindow window = new ParametersWindow();
                EventHandler closeHandler = null;
                closeHandler = (sender, e) =>
                {
                    window.Closed -= closeHandler;
                    args.Callback();
                };
                window.Closed += closeHandler;
                window.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

1. You need `Prism.Core` and `Prism.Wpf` dlls (at least) to make this code work.
2. `ShowWindow` method, will trigger the `Invoke` method of the `ShowWindowAction`, which will really show the window.
3. you can handle the closing of the window in the `OnWindowClosed`, which we passed it as a callback to the `ShowWindowAction` class, and we called it from there when the the window really closed.

Comment: What's the difference? The `PopupWindowAction` is still there in Prism 6 (https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Interactivity/PopupWindowAction.cs) and both `IConfirmation` and `Confirmation` classes are still present in both frameworks. Except that Prism5 was (at that point) still maintained by MS and Prims6 is no in community hands, nothing on the usage of the classes changed. There is no need for own `TriggerAction` except when you need something that `PopupWindowAction` doesn't offer (i.e. lazy loading, that I required fresh view and viewmodel on each call)

Comment: @Tseng yes you are right, I think the differences is the namespaces, the classes is still exists, but the namespaces has changed. Also I just provided another way by using custom `ActionTrigger` *maybe this could be helpful for others*, also I am using an `i:EventTrigger` instead of  `InteractionRequestTrigger`, but yes in general our answers is very near to each other.

Comment: What's the `ShellViewModel` in your code? Does it refer to `MainWindowViewModel`? And where should the `InteractionRequest` be located, is it in `MainWindow.xaml`?

Comment: @Shimmy you put the comment in the wrong place, I do not have `ShellViewModel` :)

Comment: OK Sorry, I'm deleting my previous comment. I have a different question tho, I have a function `Task<Credentials> GetCredentials` which I'm calling the interaction request from it. My problem is that we get the interaction result in a callback. How can I return the result from the callback to the upper function?

Comment: This answer is a little bit confusing.  It says not to use a Window otherwise it will crash, but doesn't specify what should be used instead? Edit: This is further confused by having the word "Window" in "CustomPopupWindow"

Comment: @LewisCianci you have to use 'UserControl' instead of the window, I will update my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 13):

Luckily, Prism 5.0 (and I assume 6.0 too, haven't worked with it yet), has a class called `InteractionRequest<T>` which you can use from code to raise interaction requests.

An interaction request is basically a window, that asks the user for a certain action and calls a callback (if necessary or desired) with the users decisions/actions.

```
public class ShellViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly IRegionManager regionManager;

    public ShellViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        if (regionManager == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("regionManager");

        this.regionManager = regionManager;
        this.OptionSettingConfirmationRequest = new InteractionRequest<IConfirmation>();

        openConnectionOptionsCommand = new DelegateCommand(RaiseConnectionOptionsRequest);
    }

    public InteractionRequest<IConfirmation> OptionSettingConfirmationRequest { get; private set; }

    private readonly ICommand openConnectionOptionsCommand;
    public ICommand OpenConnectionOptionsCommand { get { return openConnectionOptionsCommand; } }

    private void RaiseConnectionOptionsRequest()
    {
        this.OptionSettingConfirmationRequest.Raise(new Confirmation { Title = "Options not saved. Do you wish to save?" }, OnConnectionOptionsResponse);
    }

    protected virtual void OnConnectionOptionsResponse(IConfirmation context)
    {
        if(context.Confirmed)
        {
            // save it
        }

        // otherwise do nothing
    }
}
```

In XAML you would do something like

```
<Button Content="Options" Command="{Binding OpenConnectionOptionsCommand}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <pit:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding OptionSettingConfirmationRequest, Mode=OneWay}" >
            <pie:LazyPopupWindowAction RegionName="ConnectionSettings" 
                                NavigationUri="ConnectionSettingsView" IsModal="True" />
        </pit:InteractionRequestTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

I used my own implemetation of `PopupWindowAction` (see github project page for it's implementation) called `LazyPopupWindowAction`, which will instantiate the embedded `ConnectionSettingsView` View on click. If you don't care that your view is instantiated only once, feel free to use `PopupWindowAction`, then it will be instantiated at the same time as the View containing the action.

It's basically copy & paste with cutting some useless lines from one of my projects. I used `IConfirmation` and `INotification` interfaces instead of the concrete implementations.

XAML with `PopupWindowAction`

```
<Button Content="Options" Command="{Binding OpenConnectionOptionsCommand}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <pit:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding OptionSettingConfirmationRequest, Mode=OneWay}" >
            <pi:PopupWindowAction>
                <pi:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                    <views:CustomPopupView />
                </pi:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            </pi:PopupWindowAction>
        </pit:InteractionRequestTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Namespace declarations

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:pi="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity"
xmlns:pit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity.InteractionRequest;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity"
xmlns:pie="clr-namespace:MyProject.UI.Prism.Interactivity;assembly=MyProject.UI"
```

**Update:**
Since people keep asking about the `LazyPopupWindowAction`, I've put the source in a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/TsengSR/1d3c739cfea92bb9468b). Basically it's based on the `PopupWindowAction` from Prims 5 (and for Prism, haven't test it with Prism 6 yet, probably won't work w/o adjustments) and does the exact same thing, but also adds Region and Navigation support with the opened window, something that I needed in my application.

One thing I disliked about the default implementation was, that the view and it's viewmodel will be instantiated at the same time the Shell gets instantiated and the ViewModel remains in it's state, when you close it (it was actually just hidden).

Comment: thank you for giving me some idea..regarding this...THANKS YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: According to [**this link**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Interactivity) this library has been *Deprecated*, do you any other solutions for Prism 6, Thanks.

Comment: Another note : how do you set `Label="Options"` of the `Button` class, there is no property like this for the `Button`. Do you mean `Content="Options"` instead ?

Comment: @HakamFostok: And yes, it was meant to be `Content='"Options"`, most of the code I copied over from a project I was working at that time and retrofitted it. I was using RibbonControlsLibrary and it's `RibbonSplitButton` which uses `Label` rather than `Content` for the description

Comment: How do I cause the interaction from a different place outside the `ShellViewModel`?

Answer (score 10):

**This answer is for Prism 7 only,
 if you use a previous version of Prism (6 and below)
 then this answer is NOT for you**

Prism 7 changed the way of opening new windows drastically.
 
Here is the [offical documentation](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/dialog-service.html) if you want to read it.

Here is also a [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/swe4XTksiLI) explaining this idea by the creator of the Prism library.

---

Prism 7 introduced [`DialogService`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/3ab9483145e383d85f69a8660835de4a7da80cdf/src/Forms/Prism.Forms/Services/Dialogs/IDialogService.cs), a completely new way to open new window.

1. Create new UserControl.xaml which will represent the content of the window. 
   the simplest, empty content could be

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourUserControlName"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

2. Create the corresponding view-odel for this view. 
   This view-model **MUST** implement [`IDialogAware`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/3ab9483145e383d85f69a8660835de4a7da80cdf/src/Forms/Prism.Forms/Services/Dialogs/IDialogAware.cs) interface. 
   Here an example

```
public class BaseDialogViewModel : IDialogAware
{
    public string Title { get; }

    public event Action<IDialogResult> RequestClose;

    public virtual void RaiseRequestClose(IDialogResult dialogResult)
    {
        RequestClose?.Invoke(dialogResult);
    }

    public virtual bool CanCloseDialog()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public virtual void OnDialogClosed()
    {

    }

    public virtual void OnDialogOpened(IDialogParameters parameters)
    {

    }
}
```

3. You have to register the Dialog like this

```
public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    // replace 'YourUserControlName' with the class of the view which you created in setp 1
    containerRegistry.RegisterDialog<YourUserControlName>();
}
```

4. The last step is to show the dialog whenever you want 
   Usually, you want to show the dialog when the user clicks on the button or does an action,  
    so the following code usually will be executed when some command executed, 
    but again it is up to you.

```
_dialogService.ShowDialog(nameof(YourUserControlName), new DialogParameters(), action);
```

- the `_dialogService` is of type `IDialogService` and is injected in the view-model, where you will use it, example

```
public MainViewModel(IDialogService dialogService) 
{
   this._dialogService = dialogService;
}
```

**Al the Previous steps are required to show the window**.

---

There are some other optional steps **If you want them (Not required)**

1. You can specify the properties of the Window by adding the following 
   `prism:Dialog.WindowStyle` xaml element

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourUserControlName"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">

    <prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="prism:Dialog.WindowStartupLocation" Value="CenterScreen" />
            <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize"/>
            <Setter Property="ShowInTaskbar" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized"/>
        </Style>
    </prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>

    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

2. You can create an extension method for the functionality of showing the window

```
public static class DialogServiceExtensions
{
    public static void ShowWindowTest(this IDialogService dialogService, Action<IDialogResult> action)
    {
        dialogService.ShowDialog(nameof(WindowTestView), new DialogParameters(), action);
    }
}
```

Prism documentation **recommends** that but does **NOT require** it.

---

if you want a boilerplate setup for new Prism 7 WPF application with .NET Core 3.1, then you can check-out this [Github repository](https://github.com/HakamFostok/prism-boilerplate) 
 
It contains the above-metioned setup and a lot of other useful features for starting a WPF Prism Application.

*Disclaimer: I am the author of the repository*