# How to display login modal window atop Shell in Prism 6?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

My Prism 6 WPF MVVM modular application (with Unity DI) has to display modal login window atop Shell, after it has loaded, to ask user about username and password. (This is the demand of production target on my job.) I've read post at http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/58292 but this post is describing how to display login window before displaying of Shell but my application must display login window **atop** Shell (so Shell must be displayed on a background). Moreover, this post describes how to do it in Prism 2 but I use Prism 6 and I want to use Prism Window(WPF) as a view for login window. Below is my application structure:

[image]

Where 'AuthrizationView.xaml is Prism Window(WPF) that is login window that has AuthrizationViewModel view model in ViewModels folder and AuthrizationModel model in Models folder in 'Authorization' project in solution. And MainWindow.xaml is Shell that has MainWindowViewModel view model in ViewModels folder in 'FlowmeterConfiguration' project in solution. So I have the following questions here:

1. How to display login modal window atop Shell?
2. How to close login window when user click 'Login' button in this window after he or she has typed username and password in appropriate boxes?
3. How to close login window when user click 'Cancel' button in this window if he or she doesn't want to login?
4. Can login window be activated again and again to change the user by clicking on appropriate menu item in Shell?
5. Can I add keyboard shortcut support for such menu item?

Your help will be appreciated highly.

Comment: Look for InteractionRequest and PopupWindowAction... Prism 6 docs might be a good start https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/WPF/45-AdvancedMVVMScenarios.md#using-interaction-request-objects or a little more verbose for Prism 5 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `InteractionRequest<T>` type to trigger an interaction request in XAML which will show a new modal window. After the user enters the data, it will transport it back to the caller.

Check out my previous answer on this topic found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34129957/455493).

If you need to transport input of the Interaction Request back to the calling view, your need to implement a class that inherits from `IConfirmation` or `Confirmation` and define its fields, then use it in the callback.

From my other answers example, that would be

```
public class LoginConfirmation : Confirmation 
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public SecureString SecurePassword { get; set; }
}

public InteractionRequest<LoginConfirmation> LoginConfirmationRequest
  { get; private set; }
this.LoginConfirmationRequest = new InteractionRequest<LoginConfirmation>();
```

then call the request via

```
this.LoginConfirmationRequest.Raise(
  new LoginConfirmation { Title = "Please enter your login" }, OnLoginResponse);

protected virtual void OnLoginResponse(LoginConfirmation context)
{
    if(!context.Confirmed)
    {
        // user canceled
        return;
    }

    // user confirmed login 
    this.myAuthorizationService.Login(context.Login, context.SecurePassword);
}
```

The viewmodel of your login window needs to implement `IInteractionRequestAware` to be able to pass data back to your shell.

```
public class LoginViewModel : BindableBase, IInteractionRequestAware
{
    public Action FinishInteraction { get; set; }

    private INotification notification;
    public INotification Notification
    {
        get { return this.notification; }
        set { SetProperty(ref notification, value); }
    }
}
```

Where the `LoginConfirmation` will be in the notification property and you can set it's values there  and after calling `FinishInteraction()` the window will be closed and returned back to your shell or wherever you called it

Comment: I've tried to find your 'LazyPopupWindowAction' project on GitHub but It is not found there unfortunately. Please give a reference.

Comment: It's my own implementation, use `PopupWindowAction` instead as posted in the original answer

Comment: I've added a gist with it's implementation, but I'm not sure it will even work with Prism 6, as it was made when I worked on a Prims 5 application. Unless you want region and navigation inside this popup and want it's ViewModel to always load in it's default state (and not remember it's state from last time you opened it) and I needed it to handle the `INavigationAware.NavigatedTo` event to load data when displaying it , there is no reason to use it. https://gist.github.com/TsengSR/1d3c739cfea92bb9468b. It's to long to post it as or with in an answer. The name may be a bad choice though ;)

Answer (score 1):

The trick is in this situation is to have your 'popup' UI sat in a grid with a higher Z-order than the shell content UI, and have its visibility set to 'Hidden'. Then when you need the user to login you can set the Visibility to 'Visible' and it will appear on top of your UI in the shell. 
For the Modal behavior, you need to use DispatcherFrame to create a nested message pump, which will block your main UI while the newly-visible login UI handles the users input.

There is a great article and sample code here

[Modal Controls Via DispatcherFrame](http://deanchalk.com/wpf-modal-controls-via-dispatcherframe-nested-message-pumps/)

Comment: In case of UserControl based view to display it in the Shell' region I can write the following code in Shell' constructor: this.ModuleManager.LoadModuleCompleted += (s, e) => {
if (e.ModuleInfo.ModuleName == "AuthorizationModule") {
this.RegionManager.RequestNavigate("MainContentRegion", new Uri("/AuthorizationView", UriKind.Relative)); } };  Does it not have anything like for window based view to display it as modal window atop Shell?