# Implement Pop-up (new window) using Prism EventAggregator

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, eventaggregator

I'm using Prism.Core with Eventaggregator as my MVVM Framework, and I'm navigating properly between views. I'm facing a problem in opening a view as a new Window using this framework.

I'v tried to follow this SO: 
[Prism pop-up new window in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125982/prism-pop-up-new-window-in-wpf)

but this does not apply to my architecture

I'm using this way of navigating to another view

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<OpenDetailViewEvent>()
               .Publish(new OpenDetailViewEventArgs
               {
                   ViewModelName = nameof(PartMainViewModel)
               });
```

Any help with pointing out to the correct direction is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: So where and how are you handling the `OpenDetailViewEvent`? And why wouldn't using a `PopupWindowAction` "apply to your architecture" if you are using Prism...?

Comment: You should either navigate view-first (then `ViewModelName` should be `ViewName`) or view model-first (then `ViewModelName` should be an actual `ViewModel`, not a string). Your mixture is just weird. Also, the event aggregator is meant as means of communication, not as catch-all service for those that do not want to create their own service.