# Using Prism for building a Plugin (.dll)

Tags: wpf, prism

I am developing a plugin to be used for a software I use. The software plugin is attached to the software by attaching the .dll produced from my code. Therefore, the software's documentation requires you to have a certain class (call it CPlugin) as the plugins entry point.

All the tutorials I am reading with Prism is where you initiate your project as a WPF Application. This way your project will have App.xaml and App.cs files where you start to implement your Prism framework. Compiling the code also (for a WPF application) will produce a .exe not a .dll.

The way I have my plugin setup is I start my project with a C# class. I would then create my CPlugin class and initiate all my variables and then display my MainView which creates my ViewModel and take it from there. There is no App.xaml or App.cs. I am not sure how to use Prism with the constraints I have.

This is the software I am developing the plugin for: https://www.csiamerica.com/products/etabs
Upon installation in the install directory; the API helpfile can be found which explains how to develop or initiate a plugin. Here is a sample of the relevant information:

> In your plugin, all functionality must be implemented in a class called cPlugin.
>
> Class cPlugin must contain a subroutine cPlugin.Main that has two
> reference arguments of types ETABSv1.cSapModel and
> ETABSv1.cPluginCallback

Also

> Adding a .NET Plugin
> The process for adding a .NET plugin is much simpler. In the External Plugin Data form, the user should simply browse for and select the plugin .NET DLL and click the "Add" button

Here is some sample code for a plugin that displays an empty window:
Create a C# Class Library file (.NET Framework), reference the API as one of my references.

**CPlugin.cs:**

```
using Combonito.Views;          // Access Views (open window)

using CSiAPIv1;                  //to Access ETABS/SAP2000 API
using System;
using static Globals;

namespace Combonito
{
    // cPlugin has to be implemented in ETABS Plugins, it has to contain two functions Main() and Info()
    public class cPlugin
{

    private MainView _MyForm;

    //Entry point of plugin - has to exist with this exact signature
    // must call Finish() when plugin is closed!
    public void Main(ref cSapModel _SapModel, ref cPluginCallback _ISapPlugin)
    {
        ParentPluginObject = this;
        SapModel = _SapModel;
        ISapPlugin = _ISapPlugin;

        try
        {
            _MyForm = new MainView();   //Create MainView
            _MyForm.ShowDialog();       // Display window
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {
                ISapPlugin.Finish(1);
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            catch (Exception ex1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex1);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    // return value should be 0 if successful
    public int Info(ref string txt)
    {
        try
        {
            txt = "Plugin is written by Moustafa El-sawy (mk.elsawy@live.com)";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            throw;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    //Deconstructor to clean up
    ~cPlugin()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GC.GetGeneration(0));
    }
}
```

}

I then have an empty window MainView and A viewmodel MainWindowViewModel.

Edit: Here is the boiler initial to start any plugin similar to what I showed above but has more explanation https://kinson.io/post/etabs-plugin-quickstart/

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you asking a question here?

Comment: Yes. I dont know how to use Prism for my above use case since I am not creating a C# WPF application, I am creating a C# class file.

Comment: In Prism, you define a region in XAML. You use the RegionManager to Navigate that region to a View that has been registered.  Are you doing that?  Are you executing code to navigate some region, defined in XAML to a registered view?

Comment: To attach a dll, you need to know import format of dll.  Check if MEF or Unity used for dependency injection

Comment: @Joe first step in Prism is setting up your App.xaml or App.cs to create your shell. I dont have that, so how will I use Prism?

Comment: @Ugur Not sure I follow.. My issue is that I dont know how to use Prism for my plugin. My Plugin is a C# Class file with several views (No App.cs or App.xaml)

Comment: @MElSawy, I guess you are mixing many stuff. This plugin dll has nothing to do with Prism. Prism is related how you design your application. For single view, you dont need prism

Comment: @Ugur my actual plugin has several view models and views. I think Prism will help alot with data binding and commands. I just dont know how to "inject" Prism if I dont have a App.cs/App.xaml which I think is the starting point of the Prism "foundation"?

Comment: you dont need App. you can create your custom container: https://prismlibrary.com/docs/dependency-injection/add-custom-container.html

Comment: The consuming application will have to use Prism for you to able to based your plugin module on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your starting point should be `Bootstrapper`

First you need to install:

- Prism.Unity
- Prism.Wpf

Need to create your bootstrapper based on
https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/src/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/PrismBootstrapperBase.cs

Override the virtual method to create Shell (which is your main view that contains regions

Override the virtual method to configure your container.
Finally register your views and viewmodels

P.S.: Consider using an interface for each registered type e.g. IShellViewModel

```
using Prism;
using Prism.Ioc;
using Prism.Unity;
using System.Windows;

namespace PrismTest
{
    public class Bootstrapper : PrismBootstrapperBase
    {
        protected override IContainerExtension CreateContainerExtension()
        {
            return new UnityContainerExtension();
        }

        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<Shell>();
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
             containerRegistry.Register<IShellViewModel, ShellViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

Call your Bootstrapper from your plugin :

```
Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
bootstrapper.Run();
```

Your View (Shell)

```
<Window
    x:Class="PrismTest.Shell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PrismTest"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="Shell"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding MyText}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In Shell.xaml.cs: Use your view model. This can be also automatically injected

```
public partial class Shell : Window
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
    public Shell(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _container = container;

        this.DataContext = _container.Resolve<IShellViewModel>();

    }
}
```

Your ViewModel

```
public class ShellViewModel : BindableBase, IShellViewModel
{
    private string m_MyText = "Shell ViewModel Text";

    public string MyText
    {
        get { return m_MyText; }
        set { SetProperty(ref m_MyText, value); }
    }
}
```

Your interface:

```
internal interface IShellViewModel
{
   string MyText { get; set; }
}
```

Resulting view;

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I might be a bit of a beginner to understand this. Can you take a look at this: https://kinson.io/post/etabs-plugin-quickstart/. This shows how you create a plugin. My plugin has to start from the class CPlugin (I have written in my original post). Can you just put me in the right direction on how do I modify it to implement a bootstrapper? My current work flow is CPlugin --> Opens first window --> Initialize viewmodel. First window will open other windows which are linked to other view models.

Comment: The steps for creating a custom container have a modification to the App class at the end https://prismlibrary.com/docs/dependency-injection/add-custom-container.html

Comment: @MElSawy so I have edited answer with details.

Comment: When using Unity why do you `Register<ShellViewModel, ShellViewModel>()`? Unity automatically resolves concrete types, so this statement is just confusing... esp. if you know that you could have written `Register<ShellViewModel>()`.

Comment: @Haukinger, actually I had mentioned, he should be using interfaces like IShellViewModel. I left it open

Comment: The usefulness of view model interfaces is debatable, at least the common header interfaces. They may, of course, and should, in fact, implement interfaces if they pass themselves to services.

Comment: Yes I agree, he needed a just starting point.

Comment: @Ugur Thanks alot!! This is exactly what I needed and it worked like a charm. 1) Can you expand on the use of the interface of each view model? Can you give me a practical example. 2) I noticed Prism always works with one Shell and plays with the regions within that shell window. How would I pop up a new window using Prism? I watched several tutorials and none discussed opening a new window using Prism only changing regions etc. Thanks ALOT!

Comment: You are welcome, 1) You dont need to create interface for a viewmodel. You can just use  this.DataContext = _container.Resolve<ShellViewModel>();. Interfaces are needed mostly for services, like data service. 2) Your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125982/prism-pop-up-new-window-in-wpf

Comment: @Ugur Hi, I am trying to add a modules to my plugin via the bootstrapper. I am not sure but will I need to do a post-build code to copy the .dll of my modules to my bin/debug solution folder? I am watching the Building outlook prism videos and he never does this step. Is it because hes not using a bootstrapper?