# How to create a View for print using prism (MVVM) without directly instantiating it via constructor

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, prism, di-containers

I'm working on a WPF app using prism (MVVM), and I'd like to create a View for print, which will not be displayed on GUI.
My current code is shown below, but I'd like to avoid directly instantiating a View via its constructor.

```
void ExecutePrint()
{
    var vm = new CustomViewModel();
    var view = new CustomView { DataContext = vm }; // ← I'd like to avoid this!
    vm.Print();
}
```

How can I link a View with a ViewModle in a case like this using prism?

NOTE:

1. In the code above, `CustomViewModel` is instantiated every time the `ExecutePrint` method is called. Therefore, `CustomViewModel` can not be registered as a singleton.
2. The instance of `CustomView` is used only for print. It should never be displayed on GUI.
3. In the code above, `vm.Print()` perfectly works. `CustomViewModel` can print the instance of `CustomView` via `Behavior`. All I want to do is to complete `vm.Print()` without directly instantiating `CustomView`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prism pop-up new window in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125982/prism-pop-up-new-window-in-wpf)

Comment: In the above article, it seems that pop-up window is actually displayed on GUI, judging from the code ‘IsModal = true’. I’d like to resolve my problem without displaying the print target view on GUI.

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "without displaying the print target view on GUI". In the sample code you aren't using `view` so why instantiate it? Unless it's doing some sort of side effect logic in its constructor.

Comment: If you need the view to print it, what's wrong with creating it to print it? Why do you want to avoid creating it?

Comment: @Hank I'm using `view` to print it because it is referenced by `vm` via `Behavior`. What I'm aiming to to is something like the following:  
`var vm = new CustomViewModel();`
// view is automatically instantiated somewhere by prism.
`vm.Print();`